# 'init(source:)' was deprecated in OS X 10.14: Core Image Kernel Language API deprecated

Tags: swift, deprecated, cifilter

I recently upgraded to Xcode 10.2 and my CIColorKernel code does not work anymore. CIColorKernel function returns a nil and I get the warning - 'init(source:)' was deprecated in OS X 10.14: Core Image Kernel Language API deprecated.

Is Metal Shading Language the only available alternative to CIColorKernel? Looks like MSL require creating a separate file for the custom filter and I wanted to check if there are any better options.

```
// Create custom Kernel to replace gray color with black or white.
//Kernel is nil because 'init(source:)' was deprecated in OS X 10.14.

     let Kernel = CIColorKernel( source:
            "kernel vec4 replaceGrayWithBlackOrWhite(__sample grayImage) {" +
                "if (s.r > 0.25 && s.g > 0.25 && s.b > 0.25) {" +
                "    return vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);" +
                "} else {" +
                "    return vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);" +
                "}" +
            "}"
        )

// Apply the filter
        let blackAndWhiteImage = replaceGrayKernel?.apply(extent: ((grayImage?.extent)! ), arguments: [grayImage as Any])
```

Comment: Interesting. My kernels *work* in both iOS 12 and iOS 13 beta. Maybe because I'm still targeting iOS 9.0 as the base. A new project targeting iOS 13 yield the same error as you. If your project isn't a `SwiftUI` project, what happens if you target macOS 10.13? (And for the record, you probably should consider moving to Metal, even if targeting a lower OS version works..)

Comment: Good news! Found the issue. Will be editing my answer with the correct info.

Comment: another code which doesn't respect alpha https://gist.github.com/xhruso00/a3f8a9c8ae7e33b8b23d

Answer (score -2):

The issue isn't deprication, it's in your kernel code.

Try this:

```
let testKernel = CIColorKernel(source:
    "kernel vec4 replaceGrayWithBlackOrWhite(__sample grayImage) { " +
        "if (grayImage.r > 0.25 && grayImage.g > 0.25 && grayImage.b > 0.25) { " +
        "    return vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);" +
        "} else { " +
        "    return vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);" +
        "} " +
    "}"
)
```

The only things I changed were (1) I renamed `Kernel` to `testKernel` - shouldn't matter - and changed the `if` statement to check `grayImage` instead of `s`, which is how you set up the kernel signature. It's that second change that matters.

The way I create my custom kernels is to put the code in a file, register the `CIFilter` subclass for easy consumption, and then execute this:

```
let kernel = CIColorKernel(source: openKernelFile("myKernel"))

override var  outputImage: CIImage {
    return kernel!.apply(
        extent: inputImage.extent,
        arguments: [
            inputImage as Any,
        ])!
}
```

Note the `kernel!` force-unwrap. This means that when I test, my app stops execution immediately because `kernel` is nil. The way you code it, nil is an okay value in how you declare it.

Now, the reason *you* get the warning and I don't? I'm still targeting iOS 9+. (I actually found your issue in a test project where I'm upgrading to Metal and targeting iOS 11+. As long as you **do not** target iOS 12+, you'll not get the warning. If you look at how `CIColorFilter` is defined, you'll find this:

```
@available(iOS, introduced: 8.0, deprecated: 12.0, message: "Core Image Kernel Language API deprecated. (Define CI_SILENCE_GL_DEPRECATION to silence these warnings)")
```

I feel this is poor wording. Why should you silence "GL_DEPRICATION" but claim that the "CoreImage Kernel Language" is also? Yes, it's a "dialect" of GLSL. But still.

Someday you'll likely **need** to use Metal - just not this cycle.

One last thing - one major advantage of using Metal is that it will precompile your kernel code, and I believe it would have caught this kind of error in a build.

Comment: and? Here is for example the same shader written with both `CIColorKernel` and metal shader: https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/681820/  but it doesn't explain how to use that metal shader. Could you please explain how to replace it with metal implementation now?

Comment: CIColorKernel still works but it is indeed deprecated since it uses OpenGL.